# How to get [traceparent] from headers and send via python requests?

Tags: python, python-requests, python-requests-html

I am trying automate website using library requests python.

in register step, there a [traceparent] send in headers.

[image]

I have already tried to search for {traceparent} in other libraries such as selenium or selenium-wire, searched for it in [headers, session and cookies] but I didn't find it!

How I can get this traceparent from site, to send in my post request?

Comment: `req.headers["traceparent"]`?

Comment: KeyError: 'traceparent'

Comment: is not found in headers

Comment: the traceparent exist in [Request Header, not Response Headers]